# scribble: how to make a large print PDF?

Tags: racket, scribble

I have a Scribble document (`file.scrbl`) that I'm using to make a PDF (`scribble --pdf file.scrbl`).
I want to make a large print, landscape version of the PDF.

Is there an easy way to change `file.scrbl` to have Scribble output a large-print PDF?

Answer (score 0):

A LaTeX-level solution is to:

1. Load the `geometry` package with the `landscape` option
2. Increase the document font size

To do this in Scribble, first make a LaTeX style file that loads the geometry package:

```
% texstyle.tex
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
```

second, add a paragraph with the [`'pretitle`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fcore..rkt%29._paragraph%29%29) style to your Scribble document, to insert a font-changing command

```
@; file.scrbl
@para[#:style 'pretitle]{
 @elem[#:style (make-style "fontsize" '(exact-chars))]|{28pt}{40pt}|
 @elem[#:style "selectfont"]}
```

To build the PDF, run:

```
scribble ++style texstyle.tex --pdf file.scrbl
```